# Insert new inputfield after the last inputfield problem

Tags: jquery

I want with every press on my last inputfield that a new/additional one appears.
The first press on the last inputfield works fine but after that it only works when i click on the last inputfield before a new one is created but it should work only at the current last inputfield

```
$("input").last().on("click", function () {
    console.log('NOW');
    $("input").last().after('<input type="text" placeholder="Answer">');
 });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a dynamic click event, in conjunction with the selector `:last`.

> `$('selector).click()` only attaches click events to elements that exist at that point in time, if you then dynamically add elements then they will not be included within this selection process.
>
> `$(document).on("event", "selector", function() { .... });` acts as you would like, attaching a click event to the entire document, that compares the click event to the selector depending on the 'live' page (i.e. including dynamically added components).

The code below acts as you have requested.

```js
// Add dynamic click event
// Use :last to just trigger event if last input lcicked.
$(document).on( "click", "input:last", function() {
  
  // Add new input
  $(this).after('<input type="text" placeholder="Answer">');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input placeholder="Answer">
```